# Migrating an application from JBoss AS to Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, web-applications, jboss, migration

I am trying to migrate a Spring based web application from JBoss to Tomcat. The web application uses Spring Framework, JPA, JSF, with oracle being the back end.

What are the things which I have to focus on when migrating this application?

Comment: What have you tried so far? What are the specific problems that you encountered?

Comment: Olaf: I could do a successful migration except for some minor issues. Most of the exceptions I came across were Class not found exceptions. It more had to do with adding supporting JARs for application to work in Tomcat. Like javassist.jar, required JSF jars, required OJDBC jar. And thing where up and running.

Comment: Just for the record - nowadays I would wonder if anyone wanted to migrate from JBoss AS 7 to Tomcat.

Comment: @OndraŽižka I want to migrate... We have old app that runs on jboss 5. it's to painful to maintain this old jboss and nobody knows how to migrate to Wildfly 9 or 10...

Comment: @renanlf That's another question. I recommend posting a new question on this site, but I am almost sure there already is one. Also, have a look at the [Windup](http://windup.jboss.org) migration toolkit.

Comment: @OndraŽižka i know it's another question. Just answered because you said "wonder if anyone...."

Comment: @renanlf, you want to migrate from JBoss AS 5. What does it have to do with JBoss AS 7? That's like you don't want to drive last year's Ford Mustang because you don't feel good with Ford model T.

Answer (score 0):

JBoss AS is something which should provide you an environment where the libraries and frameworks are already integrated, configured, tested and tuned.

If you're really going to give that up, you'll have to focus on all of that:

Adding all libraries, syncing their conflicting versions, configure them separatedly, weave them using some IoC framework, etc etc.

*I know this answer is 2 years old, but I'd strongly recommend to look at JBoss AS 7 / [JBoss EAP 6](http://www.jboss.org/products/eap), which is way way easier to configure and maintain than 5, takes lot less memory, boots in few seconds. I migrated my apps from Tomcat to JBoss AS 7, now using WildFly 10.1.0.*